# INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'CaseStatus' is not supported

Tags: community, aura

Using lightning:recordEditForm in AURA Component which is being used under Public Community.

It was working fine until Sandbox upgrades to Spring 20.

Did check all the security/permissions on Guest Profile.

Any Solution/workaround ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is Spring 20 release issue. Log a case with SFDC support.

Comment: They're saying lightning component is out of their scope.

Comment: We've also logged a case but yet no response since 3 days. wondering if they are breaking thing then who should respond.

Comment: Have any of you gotten a solution from salesforce yet?  I just created a case with them as well.

Comment: No, the only solution I know is to use APEX class without sharing.