# How to get picklist values and translations using Aura and Apex?

Tags: picklist, aura, translation, lightning-recordeditform, pre-chat-api

**Background:**

I was using a an aura lightning:recordEditForm containing a picklist field.  This component will automatically detect user language and use the translations you have set for that field.

As of the spring 2020 release, there have been issues using this component (see [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/290344/invalid-type-sobject-type-casestatus-is-not-supported)) with the error message: "INVALID_TYPE: sObject type 'CaseStatus' is not supported"

I need to use aura in order to use the lightningsnapin:prechatApi, but I am not tied to using the recordeditform outside of the ability to translate picklist values.

**Question:**

I am trying to find a way to pull picklist values for a specific record type and the current user's language.  Is this possible? Has anyone found an efficient way of doing this?

Thanks!